# Create multirow button list dynamically

Tags: android, list, android-layout, button

I want to create a multirow Button list. Something like this :
[image]
but I want to do it dynamically(in code). Is there a way to tell layout to do this automatically? Or i have to do this myself using`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. I can do this by code but I should control so many things and I was wondering if there is another easier way to do this. For example tell layout to add elements in the next row when the current one is full!

Comment: are you trying something like GridView ?

Comment: yeah something like that but instead of data i want this full of buttons!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some more google search i finally found the best way to do this. it's so clean and simple, using Adapters and grids.
thanks for all the answers

here is a Tutorial: [Creating a Custom Adapter for Gridview(ButtonAdapter)](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/09/android-creating-a-custom-adapter-for-gridview-buttonadapter/)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this with LinearLayout and make all the buttons the same size using weight.

As for your question:

> i can do this by code but i should control so many things and i was
>   wondering if there is another easier way to do this. for example tell
>   layout to add elements in the next row when the current one is full!

This is potentially possible if you measure the screen width and height and use the Functions in in the View class to figure out the specifics of that particular view and its children.

### Alternative

But as mentioned in the comments, there are other views that you can use to solve your problem like GridView.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a table layout ,

Create first row of tabllayout in xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/goBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_weight="0.80">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:layout_weight="0.80"
                    android:background="#f0ffff" >
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/data_table"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="#006400"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/second"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="105dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/textbg"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Number1"
                        android:textColor="#006400" >
                    </TextView>

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="105dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/textbg"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Number2"
                        android:textColor="#006400" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="105dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/textbg"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:text="Distance"
                        android:textColor="#006400" >
                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="105dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="1dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="8dp"
                        android:text="F/G/H/S"
                        android:textColor="#006400" >
                    </TextView>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        </FrameLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
 </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/savescore"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I created this xml for four three texts and on button in a single row
refer to the table in onCreate

```
TableLayout extendeedTable = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.data_table);
```

add rows like

```
while (extendeedTable.getChildCount() > 1)
        {
            // while there are at least two rows in the table widget, delete
            // the second row.

            extendeedTable.removeViewAt(1);
        }

        // collect the current row information from the database and
        // store it in a two dimensional ArrayList


        // iterate the ArrayList, create new rows each time and add them
        // to the table widget.
```

// Here value is the number of rows you want in table

```
        for (int position=0; position < value ; position++)
        {
            TableRow tableRow= new TableRow(this);

            tableRow.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
//          ArrayList<Object> row = data.get(position);


            TextView idText = new TextView(this);
            idText.setText(Integer.toString(position + 1));
            idText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            idText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            idText.setWidth(10);
            idText.setHeight(45);
            idText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text2);

             tableRow.addView(idText);




             textOne = new Button(this);
            textOne.setText("CLUB");
            textOne.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text2);
            textOne.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textOne.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);//left top right bottom


            textOne.setWidth(10);
            textOne.setHeight(45);

            textOne.setId(1+position);
            tableRow.addView(textOne);

              allbtns.add(textOne);
//          textOne.setOnClickListener(this);

             textOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                  // do something when the button is clicked

                    final Button button = (Button) arg0;

                    System.out.println("value  of button is      "+
                            button.getId());

                    dialog1.setTitle(" SELECT CLUB ");         






             textTwo = new EditText(this);
            textTwo.setText("");
            textTwo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text2);
            textTwo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textTwo.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            textTwo.setWidth(10);
            textTwo.setHeight(45);
            textTwo.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
           tableRow.addView(textTwo);
            allEds1.add(textTwo);
            textTwo.setId(position +1);


            textThree = new EditText(this);
            textThree.setText("");
            textThree.setWidth(10);
            textThree.setHeight(45);
            textThree.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            textThree.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text2);
            textThree.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textThree.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            tableRow.addView(textThree);
            allEds2.add(textThree);
            textThree.setId(position +1);

            extendeedTable.addView(tableRow);

        }
```

for this i took help from here

http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial/7/

and

its xml

http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial/6/

Comment: thanks! Table layout is a good idea! but problem is i have to control the number of buttons in each row again and this might cause problems when the width of buttons are not equal. i'll give it a try if i found out that this is the only way to do this! because i hate to write some code, and after a while find out that there was a simpler solution.

Comment: if the size might be different for buttons , you can give them specific height and width , so they all will look the same.